# "but also he’s going to Greece..." or "but he’s also going to Greece..."?

Tags: word-usage, parallelism

[This site](https://www.grammarly.com/handbook/sentences/parallelism/4/parallelism-with-not-only-but-also/) says:

we can say

*He’s not only funny, but also he’s intelligent.* or

*He's not only funny but also intelligent.*

And we can say as showed in the site

*Not only is Matthew going to Egypt for a month, but he’s also going to Greece for a couple of weeks.*

My question is that, can we put "**also**" before "**he**"

*Not only is Matthew going to Egypt for a month, but also he’s going to Greece for a couple of weeks.*

In [this site](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/word-order-and-focus/not-only-but-also), they say

"**but also**" before "**the band**"

*Not only was it raining all day at the wedding but also the band was late.*

but, "**but she also**"

*Not only did she forget my birthday, but she also didn’t even apologise for forgetting it.*

Can I say:

*Not only did she forget my birthday, but also she didn’t even apologise for forgetting it.*

Also, [this site](http://www.perfectyourenglish.com/usage/not-only-but-also.htm) says:

*Not only did my uncle bring me to the city, but he also found a good job for me.*

=

*Not only did my uncle bring me to the city; he also found a good job for me.* (we can obmit "but")

Note: [this site](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/not#not__170) says

> **not only… (but) also…**: used to emphasize that something else is also true
>
> *She not only wrote the text but also selected the illustrations.*

However

> **not only… but (also)…**: both… and…
>
> *He not only read the book, but also remembered what he had read.*

Comment: "He's also going to Greece". Also modifies the the verbal phrase(going to Greece). "Also he's going to Greece". The adverb modifies the clause("He's going to Greece"). Both constructions are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Greece example

> but he’s *also* going to Greece for a couple of weeks.
>
> but *also* he’s going to Greece for a couple of weeks.

both phrases have the same meaning.  The only possible minor difference is the first sentence has more emphasis on "going to Greece" since it occurs directly after "also", whereas the second sentence has more emphasis on "he".